# Erase PE HEADER using c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to delete my PE HEADER using this function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum MemoryProtectionConsts : uint
        {
            EXECUTE = 0x10,
            EXECUTE_READ = 0x20,
            EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40,
            NOACCESS = 0x01,
            READONLY = 0x02,
            READWRITE = 0x04
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, int dwSize, MemoryProtectionConsts flNewProtect,
            int lpflOldProtect);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "RtlSecureZeroMemory")]
        private static extern void SecureZeroMemory(IntPtr ptr, IntPtr cnt);
        private static int ErasePEHeader() // hModule = Handle to the module, procName = Process name (eg. "notepad")
        {
            int OldProtect = 0;
            IntPtr pBaseAddr = GetModuleHandle(null);
            VirtualProtect(pBaseAddr, 4096, // Assume x86 page size
             MemoryProtectionConsts.READWRITE, OldProtect);
            SecureZeroMemory(pBaseAddr, (IntPtr)4096);
            return 0;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ErasePEHeader();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

However, show me all the time unhandled exception:
[image]

Launch me exception and never delete my PE HEADER in my minimal example. In this case, my goal it was delete `THE PE HEADER`, only for study purpose.

Comment: Did you read the words in the error message? *Unable to load DLL ': 'SecureZeroMem.dll': The specified module could not be found.* seems very clear. You don't have a 'SecureZeroMem.dll' to load. Where do you expect it to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as SecureZeroMem.dll - which is why your code fails to load it. If you're looking for the function `SecureZeroMemory`, it's in kernel32.dll.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint "RtlSecureZeroMemory")]
private static extern void SecureZeroMemory(IntPtr ptr, IntPtr cnt);
```

Comment: No such function in any system DLL - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232456/why-does-dllimport-fail-with-an-entry-point-of-rtlsecurezeromemory-even-t/53233193#53233193

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer uses `SecureZeroMemory()` but since its not an exported function we cannot simply call it.

However you can use `Marashal.Copy()` to copy a zero filled array to the memory

```
public static void Copy (byte[] source, int startIndex, IntPtr destination, int length);
```

see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_IntPtr_System_Int32_)